# VB Using Excel Condition Formating on Text

Tags: excel, vb.net, vba

Using VB 2010, 
I am trying to convert an excel file into VB and am struggling with this conditional formatting line where TextOperator:=xlContains)

I have got most of others done i.e. Excel.XlFormatConditionType.

```
Dim r As Excel.Range 
R = oSheet.Range("A" & CStr(FirstEmptyInColA) & ":A" & CStr(lastRow)).SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible)

          For A = 0 To UBound(AgentNames)

                BColour = BColour + 1
                If BColour > 10 Then BColour = 3
                With r
                    .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlTextString, String:=AgentNames(A), TextOperator:=xlContains)
                    .FormatConditions(r.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority()
                    With .FormatConditions(1)
                        .Interior.PatternColorIndex = oWorkbook.xlAutomatic
                        .Interior.ColorIndex = BColour
                        If BColour = 5 Or BColour = 7 Or BColour = 9 Then
                            .Font.ColorIndex = 2
                        End If
                    End With
                    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
                End With
            Next A
            r = Nothing
```

Comment: So you want just equivalent of TextOperator:=xlContains in vb.net? It means string.Contains(). Can you explain more what you need exactly?

Comment: _I guess_ you're after `TextOperator:=Excel.XlContainsOperator.xlContains`

Comment: thanks guys that's exactly what I needed, I have seen plenty of examples around but they all seem to use the same syntax as Excel, yet I have to use this the full syntax can anyone please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [FormatCondition.TextOperator documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197985.aspx):

> Returns or sets one of the constants of the XlContainsOperator enumeration, specifying the text search performed by the conditional formatting rule.

This being the case your code will be:

```
TextOperator:=Excel.XlContainsOperator.xlContains
```

As a note, [XlContainsOperator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821916.aspx) has the following operators you can use:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Should be Excel.XlContainsOperator.xlContains